# Can't see the top half of my laptop computer

Tags: troubleshooting

I've already tried plugging in HDMI to my flat screen TV. It used to work until I try to refresh to an earlier date. Now the computer will not boot up to Windows 8.1. I've got a problem when it says preparing automatic repair. It goes into preparing your PC or diagnosing your PC then it says restart I hit enter and all power shuts down and it won't boot back up until I hit the power button. When I boot back up holding the Escape button it gives one option that I can't see so I went ahead and pressed enter then it gives me two options 1 the end half says hit Itachi hts545050a7e380 I cannot see what the second option is. When I press enter on the patachi one it starts goes to a blue screen with a little waiting Circle and then it goes to a blue screen that says something about a page thread and then it goes to a black screen saying preparing automatic repair

Comment: You will probably need to bring it to an IT professional, unfortunately.  SuperUser is a one-question one-answer sort of sight, and your question is unfortunately too open-ended.  There are other websites that might work out for you, but you would need to get screenshots or precise error messages in order for anyone to help you.  Might be better to bring it to someone directly.

Comment: Is it still on warrenty ?